# array size > 0 although no key is set

Tags: php, arrays, null, ternary-operator, array-key

short question.

given the following example:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = false ?: NULL;
var_dump($arr[0]);
var_dump($arr[1]);
var_dump(isset($arr[0]));
var_dump(isset($arr[1]));
var_dump(count($arr));
```

the resulting output is:

```
NULL 
NULL 
bool(false) 
bool(false) 
int(1)
```

why does the resulting array have a size of 1 instead of 0 and is there any way to prevent this from happening when using the ternary operator? is it a bug or intended behaviour?

btw, I'm running php 5.3.3-7, but can't test it on a different version at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) returns false if the variable is not set, *or the variable is equal to* `NULL`. In this case, `$arr[0]` is explicitly set to `NULL`. This is semantically different to actually [`unset()`](http://php.net/unset)ing it: the variable is still set, it's just set to an empty value.

In short: working as intended. It's an unfortunate side effect of different functions doing slightly different things.

As a sidenote, using `foreach` on this array will actually return the `0 => NULL` key/value pair as well, as you might expect from the value returned by `count()`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. so, is there any way to avoid this behavior when using the ternary operator or do I just HAVE to use the long if(){} statement in this case?

Comment: @FlorianKernler: if you want to actually unset it, then you'll need to call `unset()`. This is because setting an element of the array to `NULL` is a valid choice and used often.

Comment: actually I was looking for something more like "do not set if empty" while using the ternary operator. setting the variable first and then unsetting doesn't sound efficient to me.

Comment: @FlorianKernler: If you are looking to conditionally set the variable, then conditionally set the variable with an `if` statement. That's why it exists.